# jQuery-UI Draggable: Print out the coordinate relative to a DIV container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events) shows how send event when dragging the component around using jQuery. I have a component inside a `DIV`, and when I drag that component I want to print out the coordinate of the component **relative** to the `DIV` container, can any jQuery pro help me out here. Here is what I got so far.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 4000px; border: 1px solid black;" >
    <div id="draggable" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: black; cursor: move;">
        <div class="count"/>               
    </div>
</div>  
<script>            
    jQuery(function(){                                
        jQuery("#draggable").draggable({
            containment: "#contain",
            scroll: false,
            drag: function(){

            }
        });
        function updateCoordinate(newCoordinate){
            jQuery(".count").text(newCoordinate);
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the callback event for drag, I need to figure out the `pageX, pageY` as well as the `offsetX, offsetY` to find out the relative position of the component when i drag. I am very new to jQuery. I know that I can obtain the both `pageX, pageY` and `offsetX, offsetY` like this

```
jQuery("#container").click(function(event){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    var pageX = event.pageX;
    var pageY = event.pageY;
});
```

but I am not sure how to combine them together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aasFx/36/

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        containment: "#contain",
        scroll: false,
        drag: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var thisPos = $this.position();
            var parentPos = $this.parent().position();

            var x = thisPos.left - parentPos.left;
            var y = thisPos.top - parentPos.top;

            $this.text(x + ", " + y);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Take a look at `drowe` solution as well. I think it really clean.

Answer (score 10):

What you might want to do is set the parent container CSS to 'position: relative', and the 'draggable item' to 'position: absolute'.  Then, using things like $(this).position().left / top will be relative to the parent container.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bTULc/1/

Comment: I like your solution a lot but `kingjiv` answered first, so I have to accept his answer. Thank you very much, btw. +1

Comment: Worked like a charm :)